# javac: invalid flag: .... in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Everything was running fine so far. My application library was compiling fine. The .jar was being created fine. Then suddenly this error has come. I created some packages like this:

```
 Status.UIComponents
 Status.UI
 Status.UIFrames
 Status.Db
```

I've added a class named `View_All` inside `Status.UIFrames`. OK.

Again added a class named `'View_All_Items'` inside `'Status.UIFrames'`. OK.

Again added a class named View_Items inside 'Status.UIFrames'... Now the error comes.

```
ant -f D:\\PEAS\\#Library\\courier -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build
Updating property file: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\classes
Created dir: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\empty
Created dir: D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 54 source files to D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\build\classes
javac: invalid flag: D:\PEAS\
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\nbproject\build-impl.xml:929: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\PEAS\#Library\courier\nbproject\build-impl.xml:269: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**What I've tried:**

1. I've deleted the last class and created another class with a different name. A blank class. error stays the same.
2. I've deleted all the classes and packages and recreated them. Error stays the same.
3. Renamed all the packages. The error stays the same.

I think there is no error inside the classes. Because all of them are compiling fine. I've noticed that a package with more then five classes creates the error. Any solution ?

Comment: Do you mean your package is ` --Status.UIFrames`? Have you tried removing the hyphens? Not sure if Java even allows that.

Comment: There is no hyphen in the package name. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has faced the similar problem, go to the `build-impl.xml` file and find the  `fork="${javac.fork}"` and delete the attribute. I do not know what it is, but it works. If someone knows better, let us know.

[image]